# A function where its Fourier transform satisfies $\operatorname{Supp} \hat{f}=\{0\}$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, lp-spaces, harmonic-analysis, fourier-transform

I did not understand why, if $\operatorname{Supp} \,\hat{f} = \{0\} $ for a given function $f$ in $L^p(\mathbb R^n)$; $p<\infty$, then  $f=0$ ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Well, the fact that $\mathcal{F}$ is an $L^2$ isometry should give you quite a bit to think about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $f \in L^p$ then $f$ generates a tempered distribution $T_f$ through $\langle T_f, \phi \rangle = \int f(x) \, \phi(x) \, dx$, and also $\hat f$ is a tempered distribution.

In the space of (tempered) [distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)), if $\operatorname{supp} \hat f = \{0\}$ then $\hat f = \sum_\alpha c_\alpha \partial^\alpha \delta$ for some constants $\alpha$. Here $\alpha$ is a [multi-index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-index_notation). This means that $f(x) = \sum_{|\alpha|\leq N} \bar c_\alpha x^\alpha$ for some $N \in \mathbb N$, where $\bar c_\alpha$ is closely related to $c_\alpha$ (by a factor $(2\pi)^n$ or something like that).

But $\sum_{|\alpha|\leq N} \bar c_\alpha x^\alpha \not\in L^p$ unless $\bar c_\alpha = 0$ for all $\alpha$, i.e. unless $f = 0$.

Thus, $f = 0$.

Comment: The first statement does not seem to me to constitute a proof.  The question asked about the situation where $f\in L^p$.  For $p>2$ it does not follow that $\widehat{f}\in L^q$ for any $q$.  However the statement about distributions is true, and I believe implies the original question (as no polynomial is in $L^p$).

Comment: @felipeh. You are of course correct, and I have therefore modified my post.